# How to use ca cert in elasticsearch sink connector configuration for kafka-connect confluent platform?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am currently trying to configure an elasticsearch sink connector on a kafka-connect cluster in distributed mode. This cluster is deployed in kubernetes using the helm charts provided by confluent.
Here is the properties json file.( i use username passwd to connect to elastic- removed it from the json file for security purposed)

````
  "name": "elasticsearch-sink-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "transforms": "dropPrefix",
    "config.action.reload": "restart",
    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
    "topics": "_audit_log",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name": "_audit_log_dead_letter_queue",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor": "1",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.regex": ".*",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement": "audit_log",
    "connection.url": "https://path_to_elastic_cloud:9200",
    "auto.create.indices.at.start": "false",
    "type.name": "",
    "key.ignore": "true",
    "schema.ignore": "true",
    "drop.invalid.message": "true",
    "elastic.ca.cert.path": "/opt/xyz/elastic/certs/tls.crt",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"
  }
}```

but here are the error logs from the connect cluster.

    [INFO] 2020-11-04 19:13:53,384 [task-thread-Brians-0] io.searchbox.client.AbstractJestClient setServers - Setting server pool to a list of 1 servers: [https://path_to_elastic_clound:9200]
[INFO] 2020-11-04 19:13:53,385 [task-thread-Brians-0] io.searchbox.client.JestClientFactory getConnectionManager - Using multi thread/connection supporting pooling connection manager
[INFO] 2020-11-04 19:13:53,386 [task-thread-Brians-0] io.searchbox.client.JestClientFactory getObject - Using default GSON instance
[INFO] 2020-11-04 19:13:53,386 [task-thread-Brians-0] io.searchbox.client.JestClientFactory getObject - Node Discovery disabled...
[INFO] 2020-11-04 19:13:53,386 [task-thread-Brians-0] io.searchbox.client.JestClientFactory getObject - Idle connection reaping enabled...
[INFO] 2020-11-04 19:13:53,387 [task-thread-Brians-0] io.searchbox.client.JestClientFactory getObject - Authentication cache set for preemptive authentication
[ERROR] 2020-11-04 19:13:53,410 [task-thread-Brians-0] org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask doRun - WorkerSinkTask{id=Brians-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Couldn't start ElasticsearchSinkTask due to connection error:
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.<init>(JestElasticsearchClient.java:168)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.<init>(JestElasticsearchClient.java:152)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.start(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:74)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.start(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:302)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:193)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:235)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:326)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:269)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1339)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1214)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1157)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:422)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1309)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:411)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.executeRequest(JestHttpClient.java:133)
    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:70)
    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:63)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.getServerVersion(JestElasticsearchClient.java:316)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.<init>(JestElasticsearchClient.java:161)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1323)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)```

any pointers are deeply appreciated. Thank you.
````

Comment: What JVM arguments did you add to the container? Did you add any keys to the keystore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. Earlier we werent using any keys to the keystore. Finally was able to add these to the config(not real values)after following instructions from this ticket on github. Very helpful.

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/issues/432

```
    "elastic.security.protocol": "SSL",
"elastic.https.ssl.keystore.location": "/mnt/secrets/elastic/keystore.jks",
"elastic.https.ssl.keystore.password": "changeit",
"elastic.https.ssl.truststore.location": "/mnt/secrets//elastic/truststore.jks",
"elastic.https.ssl.truststore.password": "changeit"
```